# Computer keeps freezing after ubuntu installation

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, ubuntu, freeze

Recently, I decided to shift to Ubuntu 20.04. So, I installed it on dual boot setup along with my already installed Windows 10. It worked great for 3 days (great enough for me to shift a lot of my stuff to Ubuntu and install and customize everything) and when I had finished settling in, Ubuntu started freezing every time after booting on opening applications like Chrome, VS Code, or even Terminal.

**I TRIED A LOT OF STUFF** (trust me, asking a question requires much more effort than researching) from the already existing answers (like increasing swap memory on Ubuntu, downloading third-party cleaner softwares etc.) but of no use. So I decided to revert back to Windows (thankfully I had it on dual boot). But, the exact same thing started happening on Windows.

Finally, I decided against keeping Ubuntu and deleted the Linux partition (the GRUB files are still on my PC though) and was really optimistic about the situation being fine after I did that, but voila - my high-end PC which ran perfectly smooth has started freezing.

So, here is a summary of what I tried:

1. Clear cache memory, RAM.
2. Running scans for faults in Hard Disk.
3. Updating NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu.
4. Disabling secure boot to apply fixes on login.
5. Increased swap memory on Ubuntu.
6. Tried nomodeset option.
7. Deleted Ubuntu partition (from Windows).

Please help!

**UPDATE:** I think I may have found an answer in my case; there was a faulty extension that I developed in Ubuntu and used it in chrome on both my OS. I am not sure about this and if this is the case, it may not be of much help to future readers (but thank you for the comment and answer).

Comment: Have you deleted Ubuntu from the boot menu? Does your computer use BIOS or UEFI?

Comment: Yes, I have deleted it. It uses UEFI. What could've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer without more data.
You might find some error messages in the Event Viewer that could point to the problem.

Without more information, all I could counsel is to start with
[How to Run a Startup Repair in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

If that does not help, you could have a look at
[How to Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

This operation has the same impact as any major upgrade of Windows and keeps all
settings and applications.

Comment: I'm sorry that I couldn't provide much helping information, but isn't startup repair supposed to fix just startup issues? My OS boots properly and freezes only when I open up some things.

Comment: In-place Upgrade will do everything that Startup Repair does. I advice it as a way to ensure that Windows is in a known state, as without more info I have no handle upon the problem. Have you looked for error messages in the Event Viewer?